# Compression using curve fitting or regression. Want to compress an exponentially increasing series

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, compression, regression, curve-fitting

I want to compress the data as below.

```
10 104 1006 2010 10043 20311 102343 ...
```

The data is always in increasing order. It's in range between 0 and 1 million.

I was using polynomial curve fitting but didn't get acceptable results as i am not fluent in any language. I just try to make things work. Python code will do.

Comment: Have you considered taking the log of the data? That might work.

Answer (score 0):

Fitting an exponential to that example you're only going to get one or two more points before you hit a million. That is simply not enough data to get any noticeable compression on, no matter what you fit it to.

Comment: the  data that im compressing is much bigger

Comment: You need to better describe the data then.